# Azure search: use a single index on multiple data sources

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have multiple Azure tables across multiple Azure storage that have the exact same format. Is it possible to configure several data sources in Azure-search to use a unique Index so that a search on this Index would return the results aggregated from all data sources (Azure tables)?

So far, each time I configure a new 'Data Sources' and the corresponding index, I must create a new index (with a new index name). Attempting to reuse an existing index name results in an error stating "Another index with this name already exists"

Thank you for any help or pointer you might provide.

Comment: How are you creating the Data Source and index? Via the Azure Portal? REST API? .NET SDK...?

Comment: I am creating the Data Source and Index via the Azure Portal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but we don't currently support it in the Azure Portal.

When you go through the "import data" flow in the portal, it'll create a data source, indexer and index for you.

If you want more sources for that index, you need to create new data sources and indexers, with the new indexers pointing at the existing index. Unfortunately this is not currently supported from the portal. You can do it using the .NET SDK (if you're using .NET), directly using the REST API from your app, or using any tool that can make HTTP requests such as PowerShell, curl or Fiddler.

The documentation that describes the indexer-related REST APIs is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946891.aspx

Comment: From the link you sent, I see that the REST API supports management for Azure SQL DB, Document DB and Azure Blob Storage in preview. Are Azure Tables also supported like they are on the Azure Portal?

Comment: It looks like the current rest API does not allow the creation of Data Sources for azure tables, is that correct? The documentation does states that only 'azuresql' and 'documentdb' are supported, but the portal supports azure tables. Is there a keyword for the 'type' parameter that would work? (azuretable does not as shown in the response I got below: {
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Data source type 'azuretable' is not supported for this API version"
    }
}