# How to combine multiple index in azure cognitive search?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have 3 different indexes, and I want to combine into one. Is there anyway we can combine multiple indexes into one index, so that I can search that single index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but how you do it depends on what data sources you are using and how you set them up.

You can define a data source, indexer and index via the portal. You can have multiple data sources/indexers for a single index, but you need to use the REST API to set this up [as explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946891.aspx). You cannot do this via the user interface in the Azure Portal.

[image]

See a previous post from 2016 about multiple indexers per index: [Azure search: use a single index on multiple data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380370/azure-search-use-a-single-index-on-multiple-data-sources)